# I'm struggling to get 'beautifulsoup4' working in pycharm on my windows10 laptop

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm

Pycharm seems to accept bs4 but doesn't recognize beautiful soup - even though i've made sure it is installed via pip in the command terminal and via miniconda. I've also gone to settings (in pycharm) and
have the packages bs4 and beautifulsoup4 installed already (with the latest versions), I am using Python 3.9.
The following is the error message I get:

```
C:\Users\joe_h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/joe_h/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joe_h\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup4' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\joe_h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: hi, perhaps try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
```

(which is wrong way to do it)

instead do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I had actually already tried this but may have been before I made sure pycharm had it uploaded in the settings. Either way, it seems to work now, thank you